# To know what theme functions are available

Tags: theming

I wonder if there is any method to obtain all available options for `theme()` function in Drupal installation? (I mean those one that are declared through `HOOK_theme()`). Or at least a resource where the most common uses are noted.

P.S. This is not trivial question for me, because almost every module introduces its own hooks for theming and if I don't know about them I can not leverage from theming opportunities. For example if I don't know about `theme('table', ....)` or `theme('fieldset', ....)` I have to write my own hooks that, e.g., another developer in his turn will  not be heard of, etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default theme implementations for Drupal core can be found listed here:

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21theme.api.php/group/themeable/7

If you want the theme functions for contrib as well, you could use [hook_theme_registry_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7) on your install and dump out the theme registry with [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) to list all the theme implementations.

e.g

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_registry_alter
 */
function mymodule_theme_registry_alter(&$registry){
  dpm($registry); // requires devel module
}
```

Comment: be prepared to welcome a massive array of at least 300 items in it :)

Answer (score 3):

There are over 200 theme hooks in Drupal 7 core, you should not need to know all of them, since most of them will never need to be called, or overridden.

Think about the markup you would like to produce, and then either search the [drupal API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_item_list/7) for a function that provides that markup, or look at a module that already produces something similar, and use the function they use.